# Haskell: Multi-property sort is not generic enough

Tags: sorting, haskell, generics

I was trying to implement a ranked multi-property sort that works on lists of anything.

```
import Data.Ord (Ordering, Down (..), comparing)
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

data Order a = ASC a | DESC a

orderBy :: Ord b => [Order (a -> b)] -> [a] -> [a]
orderBy rankedProperties unsorted = 
    sortBy rankedCompare unsorted 
    where 
        rankedCompare x y = 
            mconcat $ map 
                (\property -> 
                    case property of 
                        ASC  f -> comparing f x y
                        DESC f -> comparing (Down . f) x y
                ) rankedProperties
```

It works now for tuples and records, however I've discovered a problem. The problem is that the `b` in `orderBy` has to be the same. That is consider this:

```
data Row = Row { shortListed :: Bool, cost :: Float, distance1 :: Int, distance2 :: Int } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I want to be able to say: `orderBy [ASC shortListed, DESC cost] listofrows`.

But the error that comes back is:

```
<interactive>:1:31:
    Couldn't match type ‘Float’ with ‘Bool’
    Expected type: Row -> Bool
      Actual type: Row -> Float
    In the first argument of ‘ASC’, namely ‘cost’
    In the expression: ASC cost
```

I need a way to make the `b` type generic, as the `b` only really has to be acceptable by the `comparing` function `comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering`.

I've read a little bit about existential types and heterogenous lists, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we have `Monoid Ordering` and `instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)` in `Prelude`, we also have `Monoid (a -> a -> Ordering)` by iterating the function instance twice. This lets us solve the issue quite simply, without existentials:

```
import Data.Ord (Ordering, comparing)
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Monoid ((<>), mconcat)

data Row = Row {
  shortListed :: Bool,
  cost :: Float,
  distance1 :: Int,
  distance2 :: Int
  } deriving (Show, Eq)

asc, desc :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
asc  = comparing
desc = flip . asc

list :: [Row]
list = [Row False 0 10 20, Row True 10 30 40]

list' :: [Row]
list' = sortBy (asc shortListed <> desc cost <> asc distance1) list
```

Alternatively:

```
orderBy :: [a -> a -> Ordering] -> [a] -> [a]
orderBy = sortBy . mconcat

list'' :: [Row]
list'' = orderBy [asc shortListed, desc cost, asc distance1] list
```

Comment: I was thinking of just accepting a function that produces an `Ordering`, but I thought it would create too much noise with repetitive `comparing`. However I didn't realise to just wrap the `comparing` into the ascending and descending constructors.